# Cant read file name when Input through cmd in C ( through args[1] )

Tags: c, gcc, command-line, command-line-arguments, object-files

This is how I am reading my text files in cmd. It is a constraint.

```
>gcc -std=c99 myproject.c -o myproject
>myproject<1.txt
```

What I'm trying to achieve is the file name "1.txt" as a string so that I can read the number for lines in the file.
I looked through a bunch of solutions and all of them suggest argv[1] but when I do this:

```
int main(int args, char*argv[]) {
printf("File: %s\n", argv[1]); }
```

it prints null.

args gives 1 and argv[0] gives myproject.
I don't know what else I could try. All I want to achieve the number of lines in the given input file. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Why did you put the `<` there? remove it.

Comment: @tkausl Hi, that's how the script is for reading the project.

Comment: `myproject<1.txt` doesn't pass any arguments to `myproject`. `myproject 1.txt` does.

Answer (score 2):

Using redirection (<) gives the data to the program on the standard input (the program sees the data just as if they were typed in by the keyboard), if you want to pass just the parameter simply delete the redirection.

```
myproject 1.txt
```

... if you just want to 'count lines' give a try to the command `wc -l`, if it's a homework, just check you're dealing with the file in the correct way: Use fscanf, fgetc,  fputs, fputc, ... instead of the 'standard input' ones scanf, gets, getc, putc, ...

Comment: This doesn't work for me as it just gives the file name but the rest of the program freezes.

Comment: May the issue be in the 'rest of the program'? (As you said the code above code 'prints the filename' which is what it has to do)

Comment: What is the rest of the program? Using that syntax with the short program you wrote in the OP should work